# Yates' correction for continuity only for 2X2?

Tags: contingency-tables, yates-correction

Is the Yates' correction for continuity used only for 2X2 matrices?

Comment: Read carefully: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates'_correction_for_continuity

Comment: @mbq I did read the Wikipedia article but I wanted to confirm and verify it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's derived for binomial/hypergeometric distributions, so it's applicable to 2x2 or 2x1 cases.