Continuity correction in a 2 proportion test, with different sample sizes
In a test of 2 proportions (binomial -> Normal), when the sample sizes are different, what does a continuity correction look like?
Usually, in a 1 sample test, we would divide by $n$ (sample size) the $\frac{1}{2}$ term. However, with different sample sizes, what should we do?
For more context, let's assume we have a sample from a discrete distribution $F_{X}$, with $E(X)=\mu$ and $Var(X) = \sigma^2$, and we'll approximate probabilities by $\frac{\bar X - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}\sim^a N(0,1)$.
A book I'm reading states that in this case, we should use the following continuity correction:
$P(\sum X_i \leq c) = P(\sum X_i \leq c+1/2) = P\left(\frac{\bar X - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}} \leq \frac{(c+1/2)/n - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}\right)$
This last expression can be approximated by $\Phi\left(\frac{(c+1/2)/n - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}\right)$
This can be applied whether the $X$ follows a Poisson, or a Bernoulli...
My question concerns how this technique would generalise to the case of 2 discrete populations, $X_1 \sim F_1, X_2\sim F_2$ (both bernoulli, for now... I'll search to see if it makes sense for other type of distributions like Poisson)
$\frac{\bar X_1 - \bar X_2 - (\mu_1 - \mu_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_1^2 }{n_1}+ \frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}}}\sim^a N(0,1)$
with $n_1\neq n_2$.

Could you cite the division by $n$?  Where is that recommended?

Can you show what form of test statistic you're using when you don't use correction? It would help to know what formula to correct

The reasoning would be something along the lines $P(\sum X \leq c+1/2) = P(\bar X< \frac{c+1}{2n} ) \approx \Phi(\frac{\frac{c+1}{2n}-\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}})$...

In this question (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568089/continuity-correction-in-proportion-test) it suggests that the test is equivalent to the chi-square test for independence so you would do the continuity correction in the same way.

@whuber added a comment with more info. Regarding where it's recommended, it's in an old non-english book I have.

@Glen_b added a comment with info on the case of 1 proportion. For a two-proportion, we would use $\frac{\bar X_1 - \bar X_2 -  (\mu_1-\mu_2)}{\sqrt(\frac{\sigma_1}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma_2}{n_2})}\sim^a N(0,1)$


Here the underlying $X$'s making up those $\bar{X}$s are binary so these $\bar{X}$s are proportions? The scale of what's averaged affects the correction. Or are the $X$'s a set of counts at some fixed $n$? 2. You probably want to square those two $\sigma$s and would help to define them (or define the parent $X$'s should do)


@Glen_b it can either be bernoulli, or poisson. Supposedly the correction should work for both... I've added some more context in the post. Thanks for the patience. I've realised that it was lacking a lot of information.

Sorry still some ambiguity remains in your formula which is a formula for a z test rather than explicitly what it becomes when applied to proportions vs counts. Xbar is a ssmple proportion?

@Glen_b yes, xbar is sample proportion.

Thanks for your patience. I have posted some discussion.

When using a continuity correction with a discrete distribution on a lattice, the idea is that you shift by half the interval between points on the lattice.
If the continuous cdf closely matches the location, scale and shape of the discrete one, the curve should go close to the center of the "steps" in the discrete one.
Here's an example

(image taken from this answer: Why does the continuity correction (say, the normal approximation to the binomial distribution) work? )
Looking more closely:

We can see that the approximating normal in this part (near the middle) does in fact pass quite close to the center of each vertical jump. As a result (because it's close to linear* in small sections) it also passes close to the midpoint of the horizontal line between each integer. If we want a good approximation to the cdf of the binomial at integer arguments in this region we need to shift across by one half unit.
[However, see the discussion at that linked answer, which has warnings about when the correction doesn't help. There's a second example for a case that's not related to a test of proportions here; the same issue - that a correction often helps, but not always - applies here too, despite the fact that this one is symmetric. In that case, the second differences of the log of the pmf (within the support) are not fairly smooth, let alone close to constant, as you might anticipate for a case where the normal provides a good approximation.]
For a one tailed test, when the variable on the numerator is a sample proportion, $X/n$, the lattice points (in going from integer counts $X$ to proportions $X/n$) are not $1$ apart but $\frac{1}{n}$ apart. Consequently the correction to the $x$-value when using that normal approximation is $\frac{1}{2n}$ rather than $\frac12$.
Now with a two-sample test of proportions, if they both have the same $n$, this discussion carries over; the support of possible values still on a lattice with step $\frac{1}{n}$ and so an implied continuity correction of $\frac{1}{2n}$.
When the denominators differ $-$ $n$ and $m$ say $-$ then we're dealing instead with smallest steps of the reciprocal of th least common multiple of those two sample sizes. However, not every possible step in between $-1$ and $1$ will generally be in the support. For example, with $n=5$ and $m=6$ you cannot see any differences of $11/30$, $17/30$ or $26/30$ (among a number of others), or their negatives. I haven't counted but I think about a third of the values on the lattice of multiples of $\frac{1}{30}$ are not represented in the support of the numerator of the two sample test of proportions statistic in this case.
(There's also the weirdness of a multimodal distribution of the difference, though that disappears when sample sizes are large)

I'll add in the probability (mass) function to help with picturing what's going on, since many people are less used to reading the cdf$\,$†$\,$:

You might still try to use a correction of $\frac{1}{2nm}$ but this is not usually seen in practice, in my experience. Note that because of both the gaps in support and the local modes the condition of being close to the middle of vertical jumps and local 'linearity' won't typically hold. Consequently we don't have the expectation that the approximation will pass through horizontal parts of the cdf in such a way that a shift of that size will help, and when it does help some that it would be anywhere close to the right size in general.
The two sample test is often uncorrected (though the 2x2 chi squared - which works with the distribution of counts - is fairly often corrected). I don't know that it would necessarily help very often, but one could certainly investigate further when and where the normal approximation would be improved.

* approximately linear in the sense that $F(t) \approx \frac{F(t+1)+F(t-1)}{2}$ for a variable on the integers; more generally on some other lattice of interval $\delta$, then $F(t) \approx \frac{F(t+\delta)+F(t-\delta)}{2}$
$\dagger$ albeit that the cdf is what we're approximating

thanks Glen_b for the answer and extra links ;)

Corrected an error (introduced by an incomplete edit during composition).
